# How do you find the one-sided limit of a particular function?

Tags: limits

I'm having trouble understanding the solution to the following problem:

> Given the function $f(x)=sgn(x)=\begin{equation}
>     \begin{cases}
>       1, x>0\\
>       -1, x<0\\
>       0, x=0
>     \end{cases}\
> \end{equation}$, determine the one sided limits of this function on $x_0=0$.

The solution I have in my notes is:

$\displaylines{\lim_{x\rightarrow {x_0}^-}sgn(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
{x_0}^-=x_0-\epsilon\\ 
0^-=0-\epsilon=-\epsilon, \epsilon\rightarrow 0^+
\end{vmatrix}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}sgn(-\epsilon)=-1}$

Similarly,

$\displaylines{\lim_{x\rightarrow {x_0}^+}sgn(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}sgn(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}sgn(0+\epsilon)=1}$.

Now, I don't know what the heck is going on in the solution. How is ${x_0}^-=x_0-\epsilon$ and $0^-=0-\epsilon=-\epsilon, \epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$. I just cannot see the relation between these equalities and the definiton of one-sided limits.

Comment: For a positive real number, no matter how small it is, we get $1$. Hence the limit from the right is trivially $1$. Analogue for the limit from the left. Maybe, this is better to understand than the $\epsilon$-proof.

Answer (score 1):

$x_0^-$ is the left hand limit at $x_0$ (the superscript - indicates the left hand limit at a point).
Similarly $x_0^+$ is Right hand limit.
For left hand limit we can write x is smaller than $x_0$ by infinitesimal amount.
So $x = x_0 - \epsilon $ where $\epsilon > 0$ and $ \epsilon \rightarrow 0$